# Entity Framework Update performance

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-1.1

Scenario: `Data Transfer\Link` records from the old database, updates entities into the new database based on the new schema which I have created.

Do you have any suggestions to improve these piece of code? I really need to be able to achieve a superior performance.

Thank you in advance!

```
private async Task LinkCategoriesToBillingTransactions()
{
    var legacyTransactions = _legacyDb
            .TbTransactions
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id >= 1150534);

    foreach (var legacyTransaction in legacyTransactions) 
    {
        var legacyTransactionTask = _legacyDb.TbCategories
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x =>
                                x.Id == legacyTransaction.CategoryId);
        var transactionTask = _cmDb.BillingTransactions
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => 
                                x.UniqueId == legacyTransaction.Guid);

        await Task.WhenAll(legacyTransactionTask, transactionTask);

        var legacyCategory = legacyTransactionTask.Result;
        var transaction = transactionTask.Result;

        if (legacyCategory == null || transaction == null)
            continue;

        var transactionCategory = await _cmDb.Categories
                         .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => 
                                 x.UniqueId == legacyCategory.Guid);

        transaction.Category = transactionCategory;

        await _cmDb.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Entity Framework and performance don't really go together.

Comment: If you want performance I would create a procedure in SQL, MySql, Oracle, etc. that deals with that on the back end.  Doing things in the middle data access layer with EF and wanting performance is like saying: "How can I run faster with these snow shoes?".  You may get some answers but really you are doing a SingleOrDefault which is only getting one object back at a time so I would be more worried if this was slow to begin with in what you are connecting to and why that connection is slow on doing one object returns.

Comment: Thank you @djangojazz. Will try with a sql procedure as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To increase the performance, you need to decrease the number of database round-trip.

### TbCategories && Categories

How many categories do you have? Probably maximum 5000 categories!

So load them ALL in memory and create a dictionary from it.

Instead of performing one database round-trip for every legacy transaction, you will make only one round-trip

```
var legacyCategoriesDict = _legacyDb.TbCategories.AsNoTracking().ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
var transactionCategorisDict = cmDb.Categories.ToDictionary(x => x.UniqueId);
```

### BillingTransactions

For BillingTransactions, we cannot do the same since you can have hundred of thousands of transaction.

If you can load them all, then fine! Just do the same as we did with categories otherwise load them in batch.

Something like this

```
legacyTransactionsList = legacyTransactions.ToList();
var legacyTransactionsCount = legacyTransactionsList.Count();

List<BillingTransaction> billingTransactions = new List<BillingTransaction>();
int batchSize = 2000; // Be careful, SQL is limited to 2100 parameters
for(int i = 0; i < 1 + (legacyTransactionsCount % batchSize); i++)
{
    var listGuid = legacyTransactionsList.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize).Select(x => x.Guid);
    var billingTransactionsToAdd = cmDb.BillingTransactions.Where(x => listGuid.Contains(x.UniqueId));
    billingTransactions.AddRange(billingTransactionsToAdd);
}

billingTransactionsDict = billingTransactions.ToDictionary(x => x.UniqueId);
```

You will not get all transaction in one round-trip but will improve by a lot the performance.

### SaveChanges

The SaveChanges method perform one database round-trip for every entity to save which is **INSANELY** slow.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but allows you to perform all bulk operations including BulkUpdate required by your application:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge
- BulkSynchronize

Example:

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```